# Random filter in jinja2 reuse the same value everytime

Tags: python, random, jinja2

I'm trying to pick up a value from a list randomly in jinja2, this way:

```
{{ ['#EDD7C9', '#EDD7C9', '#EEE'] | random }}
```

It selects an element randomly, but it reuses it every next time. If I change something in my template, then it picks up a different number again.

But weirdly, if I use range, it works just fine:

```
{{ range(1,100) |random }}
```

Any ideas of how I can pick a random item from a fixed list without having to create my own filters?

Just to add a more complete example:

```
{% for i in range(5) %}
    {{ ['#EDD7C9', '#EDD7C9', '#EEE'] | random }} 
    {{ range(1,100) | random }} <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

outputs:

#EEE 8

#EEE 61

#EEE 58

#EEE 64

#EEE 76

Any help is appreciated! 
thanks :)

Comment: Are you certain your browser doesn't just cache the page? `random` does what it says on the tin, but your result could still be cached elsewhere.

Comment: but then using range it should also not work, shouldn't it? And I`m also using it inside a for loop, so I should get different values at least inside the loop.

Comment: Depends on where you used it. You didn't create much of an [MCVE] here for us to verify this behaviour. But I've never had issues with`random`.

Comment: True, I added an example :)

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I got `#EEE` two times, `#EDD7C9` three times. What version of Jinja2, what version of Python?

Comment: My output: https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/104a52fe2680b32c9b641591e5d6e59b Multiple runs produce different results.

Comment: I`m using python 3.4.5 and jinja2 2.9.5. I tried your example in python3 console and I still get always the same element from the list.

Comment: I used 2.8.0 before, upgraded to 2.9.5 and can now reproduce this, but I get `#EDD7C9` all the time rather than `#EEE`. Perhaps a bug in Jinja2 has been found.

Comment: Ah, re-running the script more than once flips between options. Testing other Jinja2 versions.

Comment: This is something 2.9 introduced, digging further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug introduced in Jinja 2.9. I can reproduce it with any of the 2.9 releases (2.9 - 2.9.6). Jinja 2.8 and Jinja 2.8.1 work fine, and random values are mixed in the rendering:

```
$ cat test.py
from jinja2 import Template
template = Template('''
{%- for i in range(10) -%}
{{ ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'eggs', 'ham', 'spam'] | random }}{{ ' ' }}
{%- endfor %}
''')
print(template.render())
$ bin/python test.py    
eggs eggs eggs eggs eggs eggs eggs eggs eggs eggs
$ bin/pip -U Jinja2==2.8.1
Collecting jinja2==2.8.1
  Using cached Jinja2-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: MarkupSafe in ./lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jinja2==2.8.1)
Installing collected packages: jinja2
  Found existing installation: Jinja2 2.9
    Uninstalling Jinja2-2.9:
      Successfully uninstalled Jinja2-2.9
Successfully installed jinja2-2.8.1
$ bin/python test.py
spam ham eggs spam spam eggs eggs baz bar foo
```

Note that this *only applies to a list literal embedded in the template with `random` directly after*. If you pass in the list as a variable, then you do get a `random()` result each time; that variable can also be set in the template with `{% set ... %}`. It appears the template compiler is optimising one step too far somewhere.

So for now the work-arounds are:

- Use `{% set seq = ['#EDD7C9', '#EDD7C9', '#EEE'] %}` and `{{ seq | random }}`
- Pass in a list as a variable into the template and apply `random` to that
- or to *downgrade* to 2.8.1.

<s>I've filed [issue #739](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/739) with the project to track this.</s> The maintainers have excellent temporal skills and have fixed this [a day ahead of time](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/734). A future version will include this fix (be it 2.9.7 or 2.10).

Comment: @Earthling: and that variable can be set with `{% set var = ... %}` in the template.