# How to create a random string and use it in jinja in Ansible

Tags: random, ansible, jinja2

I would like to create a random string in Ansible tasks and use it in jinja2.
The string should contain `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z` with a length of 32 characters.

I found out this function but can't use it in a `set_fact`

```py
lookup('community.general.random_string', length=12)
```

I'm using Ansible 2.12.1
set_fact writes the string "lookup('community.general.random_string', length=12)" in me template.
I need to create once a random string to use it as passphrase in a config file. On the second run the random string should not be touched - need to add also a check if file exists or something like that.

Comment: Additionally to the already given answer, for [random filter in Jina2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965271/) you may have a look there.

Comment: _but can't use it in a `set_fact`_ > why? What happens when you try? A reason could be because your version of Ansible is too old, but you didn't provide your version of Ansible nor an error message or trial at using it, so this is just a guess.

Comment: You can use [constructed](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/constructed_inventory.html#ansible-builtin-constructed-uses-jinja2-to-construct-vars-and-groups-based-on-existing-inventory) inventory plugin, but I'm not sure this is what you want. What is the use case? Could you describe how do you want to use such variables?

Comment: I just updated my question

Answer (score 4):

A way to create a random string and then add it as a fact would be something like this

```yaml
---
- hosts: test

  vars:
    my_pass_var: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=32 chars=ascii_letters,digits') }}"
    
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_pass_as_fact: "{{ my_pass_var }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_pass_as_fact }}"
```

Comment: There is no need to have an intermediary `my_pass_var` you can use the lookup in the `set_fact` right away.